How to plot several linear equations in Python?
I have many linear equations contained in a dataframe and I want to plot these equations in Python, the equations are in this format, for example:
enter image description here
How do I do this automatically?
b = row['b']
λ1 = row['λ1']
λ2 = row['λ2']
restricao = row['Restrições']

if restricao == '<=':
    # Se λ1 for zero
    if λ1 == 0:
        plt.plot([0, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')

    # Se λ2 for zero
    elif λ2 == 0:
        plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')

    # Se λ2 for zero
    elif b == 0:
        plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')

    # Se ambos λ1 e λ2 são diferentes de zero
    else:
        plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')

elif restricao == '>=':
    # Se λ1 for zero
    if λ1 == 0:
        plt.plot([0, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')

    # Se λ2 for zero
    elif λ2 == 0:
        plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')

    # Se λ2 for zero
    elif b == 0:
        plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')

    # Se ambos λ1 e λ2 são diferentes de zero
    else:
        plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to have a minimal reproducible example. Remember to share text as text rather than images of text. Also, be sure to explain what those numbers mean because without an explanation they are useless.

First, I advise you to give your variables more conventional names. For example, instead of writing $\lambda$, I suggest writing lambda. To read each line, you can iterate with a for loop over each row and use conditions as you are doing. Alternatively, you can also use vectorized operators.

look at the gallery of examples on the web page of matplotlib

@PortorogasDS You might be surprised, but lambda isn't a valid variable name in Python. Sometimes, as a workaround, people leave out the b.

You can use iterrows():
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot(df):
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        b = row['b']
        λ1 = row['λ1']
        λ2 = row['λ2']
        restricao = row['r']

        if restricao in ['<=', '>', '=']:
            if not λ1:
                plt.plot([0, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')
            elif not λ2:
                plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')
            elif not b:
                plt.plot([0, 0], [0, 0], linestyle='solid')
            else:
                plt.plot([b / λ1, 0], [0, b / λ2], linestyle='solid')

    plt.xlabel('x-axis')
    plt.ylabel('y-axis label')
    plt.title('Equations')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'b': [-1.0, 1.0, 3.4],
    'λ1': [2.0, -2.0, 3.0],
    'λ2': [5.0, -3.0, 3.0],
    'r': ['<=', '>', '=']
})

plot(df)



Plots
Then, you can change it, however you want. Seems you have linear programming boundaries.


this way the functions are not remaining continuous
